# Is it ever ok to wash a towel that has had mineral spirits on it?

Tags: safety

I use mineral spirits as a degreaser on metal, usually removing manufacturing or packing residue. Usually, I use paper towels, let them dry, throw them in a sealable can and then store it until I have a place to drop it off.

But yesterday, I used a couple of old cotton bath towel to dry off something that was soaking in mineral spirits. The towel definitely has some on it, but very little. They are nowhere near soaked. I'd like to be able to wash and re-use the towels. I'm assuming it is safe to wash them, but I'm concerned about putting these in the electric dryer.

Is it safe to put these in a wash and or dryer? What precautions should I take before washing or drying in a machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 separate prongs to this problem.

### Allowing flammable solvents into machines and sewer systems.

We don't want to wash towels that are contaminated with flammable solvents, because the vapors will wind up all sorts of places we don't want flammable solvents.  That includes:

- Flushed down into the sewer pipe - sewer gas is bad enough!
- In the mechanisms of the washing machine where it could attack plastic components and potentially start a fire.
- Wafting through the dryer where it will make contact with hot heating elements or worse, gas burners!

### Certain flammables will self-combust

That is because they have a "curing" behavior similar to epoxy or concrete - and like most cures, it is *exothermic*.  If that heat is sufficiently bottled up, it can rise to *its own flash point* and FWOOF!  [About 1700 house fires a year are caused by this](https://www.nfpa.org/-/media/Files/Public-Education/Resources/Safety-tip-sheets/OilyRagsSafetyTips.ashx).  That generally relates to paints and stains.

However, I generally recommend developing the habit of handling *all* "oily" rags on the assumption that they will behave exothermically.  I spread them all over the shop for a week to dry out, or better, leave them out in the rain.

Comment: Yeah -- drying oils have a nice exotherm for a curing reaction.  Great on furniture, *terrible* on rags, and you can't rule that out with random-petroleum-distillates either as they might have enough olefin content to cause problems

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I’ll treat them like the paper towels. Leave them out to dry more then store until a hazardous waste drop off opportunity shows up

Comment: Absolutely agree, Harp. That's also why you don't dispose of oily rags in a garbage can.   I always spread out even oil ridden paper towels to dry before putting them in the trash. Like I said in my prev answer, even after washing them, in the dryer they caught fire and damn near burned our house down, had it not been for my parents dousing the flames.

Comment: So leaving them out in the rain also allows the solvent remains to get into drainagexsystems - something you suggest is a bad idea...

Comment: As an alternative, can they be hand washed and air dried?

Comment: Many years ago, I worked as a laborer for a pair of decorative painters. We 3 were doing a very large office space, using a rag process with linseed oil. We put our used rags in the breakroom where we were storing our equipment. After at most 6 hours, we went to properly dispose of the rags and when we disturbed the pile (somewhere between football and soccer ball sized), huge billowing clouds of smoke erupted. Considering the pile was added to slowly over the day, the heat can build up very quickly. We should have been using a 5-gal can with water to store the dirty rags before days end.

Answer (score 5):

No. Big NO! Think about the cost / risk ratio. A few dollars for a towel vs. burning down your home.   My parents were extremely frugal and once laundered towels that had paint thinner on them. In the dryer (very hot back in the day), it caught fire and would have caught the entire house on fire had they not been there to spray water on it from a hose.

Risking it to save just a few dollars on what's probably an old towel anyway just isn't worth it. It's like hmmmm this cheese expired 6 months ago, is it safe to eat? Well, it cost $3.00 so what's your deductible on your health insurance and/or copay if it makes you sick?

Answer (score 5):

You don't want fumes in the dryer or the sewer system.

You can do the following:

- Wash them in a pail in the back yard.  Use hot soapy water.  Let them soak for an hour coming by every 10 minutes or so to move them around, so that folds and creases don't hinder the soap action.
- Discard the soapy water on the lawn.
- Rinse with more hot water.
- Drain, discarding the water on the lawn.
- Go do something else for an hour, leaving the wet towels in the bucket.
- Sniff test:  Do the towels still smell like solvent?
- If no, you can put towels through laundry facilities.
- If yes, repeat above cycle.

If you start losing patience with this, dry on a line, and these become your shop towels.